# How can I prevent Firefox from blocking popup pages?

Tags: firefox, popups

[image]

Though I have unchecked the block pop-up windows option, Firefox blocks popups when there are more than 20 popups at the same time.

I have an unusual request in that I need Firefox to not block any popups even when there are more than 40 popups at the same time.

**How can I disable Firefox's popup blocking feature completely?**

[image]

In fact this page is not using the HTTP protocol, it is simply `file:///` base HTML, so I cannot set such permissions.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the warning offer a link or button to control this?

Comment: @Arjan there is a button, i can setup ignore list there, but in fact, i have bock popup option unchecked, so this is probably a bug of firefox, btw , i am using firefox 37.0.2 now

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried explicitly overriding security and permissions for the site you are looking to allow multiple popups on?

`Right click` the page, go to `"View Page Info"`. Go to the permissiosn tab and override the option to allow popups like below:
[image]

This worked for me with one of my intranet sites which uses popups for displaying a lot of info quickly.

Comment: no such option there, read edit 1 in the main question:) how many popups at the same, mine is more than 20

Answer (score 0):

The default number of maximum popups is **20**.  Normally this is a reasonable number.  There is an advanced setting to change this **limit**

1. Open a new tab
2. Type in `about:config` in the URL editbox
3. Click <kbd>Accept the Risk and Continue</kbd> button
4. Type in `popup_maximum` in the Search editbox
5. Find the entry **dom.popup_maximum**
6. It will be 20, change it to a higher limit.

**Note** this limit will apply to popups on all sites.  I have changed it to 30 on mine.

[image: Screenshot]