# How do I stop Firefox from blocking pop-up windows from a particular site (even though I've added that site as an exception)?

Tags: firefox

In my Firefox settings, I have "Block pop-up windows" checked but I also have the website "https://urltimer.com" allowed:

[image]

[image]

Nonetheless, Firefox still keeps blocking pop-up windows at that website:

[image]

I'm using Firefox Version 108.0.1 (64-bit) and Microsoft Windows 11 Home Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621.

---

Possibly related: [How can I prevent Firefox from blocking popup pages?](https://superuser.com/questions/907495/)

---

Added: I believe the problem arises when I try to open a large number of links through that website. For example, when I try to open the below list of 30 URLs at https://urltimer.com, 1 through 21 open fine, but then Firefox blocks everything else.

https://www.google.com/search?q=1
https://www.google.com/search?q=2
https://www.google.com/search?q=3
https://www.google.com/search?q=4
https://www.google.com/search?q=5
https://www.google.com/search?q=6
https://www.google.com/search?q=7
https://www.google.com/search?q=8
https://www.google.com/search?q=9
https://www.google.com/search?q=10
https://www.google.com/search?q=11
https://www.google.com/search?q=12
https://www.google.com/search?q=13
https://www.google.com/search?q=14
https://www.google.com/search?q=15
https://www.google.com/search?q=16
https://www.google.com/search?q=17
https://www.google.com/search?q=18
https://www.google.com/search?q=19
https://www.google.com/search?q=20
https://www.google.com/search?q=21
https://www.google.com/search?q=22
https://www.google.com/search?q=23
https://www.google.com/search?q=24
https://www.google.com/search?q=25
https://www.google.com/search?q=26
https://www.google.com/search?q=27
https://www.google.com/search?q=28
https://www.google.com/search?q=29
https://www.google.com/search?q=30

Comment: Are you sure the popups are actually coming from that site?

Comment: Have you opened urltimer in a new tab since adding the exception? It works fine for me using the same settings.

Comment: @music2myear: How might I check that? (And why might it not simply be the case that the pop-ups are coming from that site? I've simply entered a bunch of links at URLtimer---links that otherwise open smoothly and without pop-ups if I were to instead enter them directly into the address bar.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent Firefox from blocking popup pages?](https://superuser.com/questions/907495/how-can-i-prevent-firefox-from-blocking-popup-pages)

Comment: @RohitGupta: No. I actually linked to that same Q&A 12 minutes before you.

Comment: So you have, but you haven't stated that those solutions did not work.

Comment: @RohitGupta: What solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that as far as Firefox is concerned, **urltimer** is opening those popups (not the target sites).  By default the maximum popup at a a time is 20 (which in the normal case is heaps).  To increase this limit

- Type in `about:config` in the **url box**
- Accept the warning about it being **Risky**
- Type in `pop` in the **Search box**
- Find **dom.popup_maximum**
- Increase it to a larger number.

Caution this setting is a global setting, so all URLs that are allowed to popup will use this limit.